# Error: PythonPipBuilder:ResolveDependencies - Could not satisfy the requirement: json

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am trying to use AWS SAM to build,test,deploy AWS Lambda function by using "Hello World" SAM template.

When I have sam build command,  I got the error:Error: PythonPipBuilder:ResolveDependencies - Could not satisfy the requirement: json. However, I have already add json,requests,io boto3(required packages for my lambda function) to requirments.txt.

Is there any body know how to fix the bug?

Comment: `json` is a part of standard library, try removing it from the requirements

Comment: I was having similar issue with `requests`. I was using pycharm terminal running `sam build` and this error suddenly started coming up, it was gone after restarting pycharm.